# If in Where mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

My table has 2 columns

A: Price

B: g_Price

Logic Rules:
IF (price > 0) OR (g_price > 0) select row

BUT IF (g_price > 0 AND price > 0 AND g_price > price ) THEN do not select row

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that. There's no IF. Add sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh, what's your replace suggestion, except another -1 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "DO NOT SELECT"?

Comment: What do you mean? -1?

Comment: I'm just defined logic, that IF and BUT IF is not SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated to SQL:

```
select *
from tablename
where (price > 0 OR g_price > 0)
  AND NOT (g_price > 0 AND price > 0 AND g_price > price)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's worked. I didn't know about AND NOT :D

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE 
   (price > 0 OR g_price > 0)
   AND NOT (g_price > 0 AND price > 0 AND g_price > price))
```

This will select all line that match the condition (price > 0 OR g_price > 0) and exclude the line that match  g_price > 0 and price > 0 and g_price > price.